# Mandatory conditions to fulfil Entanglement state?

Tags: entanglement

What are the mandatory conditions for 2 qubits to be an entanglement state? Why is the Bell state $|\Psi^+\rangle= (|01\rangle + |10\rangle)/\sqrt 2$, being anti-correlated, called an entangled state?

Isn't that in a separable state, the state of each individual qubit is independent of the state of the other qubit?

Comment: A state is entangled if it cannot be written as tensor product of other states. You cannot do that for Bell state(s). You are right that in separable state you cannot infer state of a qubit based on states of other ones.

Comment: can you clarify precisely what you find unclear in the explanation found eg in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement#Quantum_mechanical_framework?

Comment: Thnx for the reply. Actually wanna confirm what conditions are necessary for qubits entanglement? Superposition and correlation? If tensor product can't be written then why Bell state (s) taken as reference for entanglement?

Answer (score 1):

You are right to note non-separability is a requirement for entanglement.  But, the Bell states are entangled because they are not separable.

For $|\Psi^+\rangle$, the statement in the question that "the state of each individual qubit is **independent** of the state of the other qubit" is not correct.  If you measure the first qubit then the second qubit collapses to be anticorrelated with the first qubit; thus, the two qubits are not independent.  The two qubits cannot be written as a tensor product of each other (you can somewhat abuse notation and say something like $|\Psi^+\rangle=|a\rangle\otimes|\bar a\rangle$, but that's still not separable).

Perhaps you are confused about whether being "anticorrelated" means being "dependent" (as you might think that only being "correlated" in the same direction, e.g. both $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$, means being "dependent").
But, even classical correlations can be anticorrelated and still be dependent on each other.  For example in a simple DC circuit with a single battery supplying a constant voltage, current is anticorrelated with resistance because as resistance increases current decreases, but nonetheless current is dependent on resistance.

---

Being "anti-correlated" does not mean the same thing as being "independent".  For example even classically, the correlation coefficient ($r$) between two variables can be positive (correlated) or negative (anti-correlated).  But the strength of the correlation is measured as $r^2$; if $r^2\ne 0$ then the two variables are not independent.  Similarly the Bell state
$$|\Psi^+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)$$

can be somewhat analogously thought of as having $r=-1$ and $r^2=1$, while

$$|\Phi^+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|11\rangle+|11\rangle)$$

can be somewhat analogously thought of as having $r=1$ and $r^2=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Confusion is that what is the true concept of correlation wr.t entanglement? For instance, if two bits AB can be perfectly correlated meaning that they always have same value like AB=00 or AB=11? Also, that means that two or more variables/qubit have a strong relationship with each other. But Anti-correlated will be like AB=01 or AB=10? (weak relationship). How come anti-correlated qubits having weak relationship get entangled?